# VS2010: Can't type a triple slash (///)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

my Visual Studio 2010 automatically changes typing a '///' to '/'. I want to add xml comments, but can't. Any help turning off that "autocorrect" feature?

Comment: Have you installed any esoteric plugins / extensions ?

Comment: Thanks, an expired AtomineerUtils did this.

Comment: Well then, uninstall it!